# Center a text link button

Tags: css

I am trying to center a text link, however, it is not responding to text-align: center;

Any thoughts? I know I am overthinking this..

HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="promotion-left">&nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="promotion-right">
      <h2 class="instructions-head">INSTRUCTIONS</h2>
      <ol class="instructions-list">
        <li class="instructions-item">INSTRUCTIONS 1</li>
        <li class="instructions-item">INSTRUCTIONS 2</li>
        <li class="instructions-item">INSTRUCTIONS 3</li>
      </ol>
      <a href="#" class="promotion-btn">Download</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.promotion-left {
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15%;
}
.promotion-right {
  background: #eaf8fe;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80%;
}   
a.promotion-btn {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0k560g1b/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to make the `a` a block element with a fixed width and `auto` margins:

```
a.promotion-btn {
  /* other styles */
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Another is to put the `a` inside a div with `text-align: center`:

```
<div class="center">
  <a href="#" class="promotion-btn">Download</a>
</div>
```

and

```
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Is this happening because the a element is nested inside an inline-block div element?

Comment: Not really, I think you're misunderstanding what `text-align: center` does. It changes the alignment of text (or child elements) within the element; it doesn't change the alignment of the element itself.

Comment: Because you're only centering the text within the `a`. You have no CSS centering the `a` within the containing `div`.

Comment: You set 100px width? what if button text gets longer?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to keep in mind what a "div" element is. It is a division, or a chunk of your HTML document. When I write websites, I admit, I go div crazy and make sure everything is organized into as many chunks as possible.

http://jsfiddle.net/1ph1wvp8/1/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="promotion-left">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="promotion-right">
    <div class="Promotion Head">
         <h2 class="instructions-head">INSTRUCTIONS</h2>

    </div>
    <div class="PromotionL ist">
        <ol class="instructions-list">
            <li class="instructions-item">INSTRUCTIONS 1</li>
            <li class="instructions-item">INSTRUCTIONS 2</li>
            <li class="instructions-item">INSTRUCTIONS 3</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="Promotion Download"> <a href="#" class="promotion-btn">Download</a>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Note, I added divs around each part of the promotion. Then I updated the css as follows:

```
.promotion-left {
background: white;
float:left;
width: 15%;
}
.promotion-right {
background: #eaf8fe;
float:left;
width: 80%;
}
a.promotion-btn {
background: red;
text-decoration: none;
border-radius: 2px;
padding: 8px 16px;
margin:auto;
}
.Download {
text-align:center;
}
.Promotion {
width:30%;
}
```

I set the width of the promotion class to 30% to keep the button under the list, otherwise it is centered to the background which looks funky to me (remove the 30% to see for yourself).